# Is it possible to turn on synch in Android Account

Tags: android, synchronization, account

I'm working on an application that will allow a user to turn on/off synching for their exchange email account.

I am able to get the exchange account using:

```
    Account[] accs = AccountManager.get(this).getAccountsByType("com.htc.android.mail.eas");
```

but the Account API doesn't seem to offer what I'm looking for. I have also found [`ContactsContract.Settings`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Settings.html) database table which stores synch data, but I'm not that sure where to start with that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The [ContentResolver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html) contains the API you are looking for.

Check out the "[setIsSyncable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#setIsSyncable%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29)" method.

Comment: Thanks for that. ContentResolver also has `requestSync()` but they both need an authority string. Any idea what this will be?

Comment: `ContactsContract.AUTHORITY` for contacts.

Comment: Hmmm... I tried that string and it doesn't seem to be doing anything. I'll keep looking...

Comment: `ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, 1);` is exactly what the EAS-client does in code to enable contacts sync.

Comment: Ok, but I want to sync email. Any idea how to kick off an email sync immediately?

Comment: Since you are apparently targeting HTC specifically you'd need to find the authority of their e-mail provider. For "normal" Android the authority of the e-mail provider is `com.android.email.provider`, if HTC has changed this you can list *all* available sync adapter types by calling `ContentResolver#getSyncAdapterTypes()` and search for `com.htc.android.mail.eas` in the `SyncAdapterType#accountType` fields that are returned. With the authority and `Account` you should be able to just call `ContentResolver#requestSync(..)`